# Connect to Google sheets via Qlik sense web connector

Tags: qliksense

I want to connect to google table through via Qlik Web Connector.
Where can I find manual, where I can step-by-step to connect via Qlik Web Connector?

Comment: When I need to get data from google spreadsheets I use the visualization API (gviz). The drawback is that you have to leave the spreadsheet public, but it may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

After installing the Web connector, go to the Gogle drive connector, connect the google drive account, on behalf of which we will connect to Google drive.
Next, in the Data load editor, select Create a new connection. In the URL field, enter the path to the google table. Done.